# How to import .js file inside my .tsx file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am having an issue where webpack is telling me:

> ERROR in ./app/app.tsx
>   (4,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module './sample-data'.

My imports look like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import { InboxPane } from './components/Inbox';
import * as Samples from './sample-data';
```

And lastly this is my sample-data.js file that I am trying to import:

```
module.exports = {
  "humans": {
    "John Smith" : {
      "conversations": [
        {
          "who": "bot",
          "text": "Hello, can I take your order?",
          "time": new Date(2016, 4, 5, 15, 10, 0, 0)
        },
        {
          "who": "human",
          "text": "Can I have a small meat-lovers pizza?",
          "time": new Date(2016, 4, 5, 15, 10, 30, 0)
        }, 
        {
          "who": "bot",
          "text": "Where would you like it delivered?",
          "time": new Date(2016, 4, 5, 15, 11, 0, 0)
        },
        {
          "who": "human",
          "text": "123 Sesame Street, Montreal, Canada",
          "time": new Date(2016, 4, 5, 15, 11, 30, 0)
        },
      ],
      "orders": [
        {
          "time": new Date(2016, 4, 5, 15, 11, 45, 0),
          "pizzas": [{
            "toppings": ["Meat-Lovers"],
            "size": "S"
          }],
          "price": 15,
          "address": "321 Sesame Street, Montreal, Canada",
          "status": "Confirmed" // status := Open -> Confirmed -> In The Oven -> Delivered
        }
      ]
    },
    "Alan Foster" : {
      "conversations": [
        {
          "who": "bot",
          "text": "Hello, can I take your order?",
          "time": new Date(2016, 4, 4, 20, 30, 0, 0)
        },
        {
          "who": "human",
          "text": "I would like to order an extra-large cheese pizza",
          "time": new Date(2016, 4, 4, 20, 30, 15, 0)
        }, 
        {
          "who": "bot",
          "text": "Where would you like it delivered?",
          "time": new Date(2016, 4, 4, 20, 30, 30, 0)
        },
        {
          "who": "human",
          "text": "123 Sesame Street, Montreal, Canada",
          "time": new Date(2016, 4, 4, 20, 30, 45, 0)
        },
      ],
      "orders": [
        {
          "time": new Date(2016, 4, 4, 20, 31, 0, 0),
          "pizzas": [{
            "toppings": ["cheese"],
            "size": "XL"
          }],
          "price": 15,
          "address": "123 Sesame Street, Montreal, Canada",
          "status": "Delivered" // status := Open -> Confirmed -> In The Oven -> Delivered
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};
```

If I change it to sample-data.ts I get told that it isn't a module. How do I go about getting this loaded into my .tsx file?

Comment: So you have `sample-data` folder ?

Comment: No sample-data.js is in the same folder as my app.tsx file where I am importing it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to import the original file without modifications try to set `compilerOptions.allowJs` to `true` in your *tsconfig.json* file:

```json
...
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true
...
```

In case you're ready to modify the file you can turn *sample-data.js* into *sample-data.ts* by using the module syntax, like that:

```js
export default {
  "humans": {
    "John Smith" : {
      "conversations": [
        {
          "who": "bot",
          "text": "Hello, can I take your order?",
          "time": new Date(2016, 4, 5, 15, 10, 0, 0)
        },
        {
          "who": "human",
        ...
};
```

You'll then need to import the file in the following way:

```js
import Samples from './sample-data';
```

You can read more on TypeScript modules [in the official docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html). In many cases  modules in TypeScript work the same way as in ES2015.

Comment: Thank you. Using the first method didn't work for me. It told me:

`cannot write file /sample-data.js because it would overwrite input file`

The second method did work though. Now I have other issues, but I don't think they are related to the importing of this file.

Comment: @j5juice, do you bundle your app using webpack?

Comment: Yes I am currently using webpack.

Comment: It could probably be a [problem with ts-loader](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/issues/171).

Comment: Are you writing files to the same directory? If so, when it transpiled sample-data.js, it will try to write it again even if no changes will made. And since the file extension is .js on both the read file and the write file, it stops to avoid overwriting the read file.

Answer (score 1):

Add the next line to `tsconfig.json`

```
...
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true
...
```

and if you get the error:
`Typescript error “Cannot write file … because it would overwrite input file.”`

add with `outDir`:

```
...
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
...
```

Answer (score 1):

## Solved it by installing types for the .js package

I had a similar issue when importing **react-helmet** inside my .tsx file. Worked it out by **installing types** for it:

`npm install --save @types/react-helmet`

If you would like to disable it site wide, you can instead edit **tsconfig.json** and set **noImplicitAny to false**:

```
 "compilerOptions": {
      ...,
      "noImplicitAny": false,
 }
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41462729/typescript-react-could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-react-material)